# Visual Studio Express 2015 For Web Builds Successfully But Hangs Forever On Debug Start

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I've spent the better part of about forty eight hours dealing with this issue.  I've read all that is said about it on this forum. (Which isn't much.)  And I've read all about it elsewhere. And I still have not found a solution.The problem.

It's simple.  My project builds successfully.  When I start the debugger, I get the endless blue loading circle.  It never launches into the browser.

If you know what the issue is, please do share I would be grateful.
Thanks,
CM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, what worked for me, was running my program in a terminal.  Completely bipassed Visual Studio's buggy UI.

I don't know what caused the infinite blue loading circle. 
And I don't care. 
I'm moving on. 
Thanks,
CM

Comment: Glad to know that it works well now, if so, please mark it as the answer. In addition, please also check that whether it is related to the property property->Web options. For example, Enable ASP.NET, disable the E&C and so. Anyway, since it works well, thanks for your sharing:)